# Countable intersection of events that are almost surely in the limit is almost surely?

Tags: probability, probability-theory

I'm wondering if the following assertion is true.

Given $\{A_{n,m}\}_{n,m \in \mathbb{N}}$ events in a probability spaces such that $\displaystyle{\lim_{n \to \infty}}\mathbb{P}(A_{n,m}) = 1$ then it holds that $\displaystyle{\lim_{n\to \infty}}\mathbb{P}\left(\displaystyle{\bigcap_{m=1}^{\infty}}A_{n,m}\right) = 1$

My advances so far are the following, if $\mathbb{P}(A_{n,m}) = 1, ~ \forall n$ it's a known result and replicating that proof we have that

$\displaystyle{\lim_{n\to \infty}}\mathbb{P}\left(\displaystyle{\bigcap_{m=1}^{k}}A_{n,m}\right) = 1, ~ \forall k$.

The problem I'm facing is that if we try the same approach we have that:

$
\mathbb{P}\left(\displaystyle{\bigcap_{m=1}^{\infty}}A_{n,m}\right) \geq 1 - \displaystyle{\sum_{m=1}^{\infty}}\mathbb{P}(A_{n,m}^{c})
$

and so we would like to say $\displaystyle{\lim_{n \to \infty}}\displaystyle{\sum_{m=1}^{\infty}}\mathbb{P}(A_{n,m}^{c}) = \displaystyle{\sum_{m=1}^{\infty}}\lim_{n \to \infty} \mathbb{P}(A_{n,m}^{c})$ but that should only be true if $\mathbb{P}(A_{n,m}^{c})$ goes to zero in such a way the dominated convergence theorem holds, so (for example) if $\mathbb{P}(A_{n,m}^{c}) \sim \frac{1}{n+m}$ we should not be able to use that method, still it feels natural that the result $\displaystyle{\lim_{n\to \infty}}\mathbb{P}\left(\displaystyle{\bigcap_{m=1}^{\infty}}A_{n,m}\right) = 1$ should hold but I've not found a proof neither a counter example, any help would be welcome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simple counterexample for a probability space $(X, A, P)$: Let $$A_{n,m}=\begin{cases}X, &(m\le n),
\\\emptyset,&(m>n).\end{cases}$$